# cron expression - 3 times a day (in one line) cadence

Tags: cron

I would like to create a cron expression for 3 times a day - 02:20, 12:30, 22:20
but I want it to be in one line (not 2 lines as I saw that suggested before)
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a pure cron definition (not a cron-based extended library), that is not possible as cron definitions are simple pattern matching and lack conditionals. I.e. you can match "minute=20" and "minute=30" but not "minute=20 if hour=2 or hour=22".

If you're willing to loosen up your requirement a bit you can achieve
e.g. 2:30, 12:30, 22:30 with: `30 2,12,22 * * *`

An other option is over-express and then implement the condition in the triggered code.

`20,30 2,12,22 * * *`  would give you 2:20, 2:30, 12:20, 12:30, 22:20, 22:30, then check in the triggered code whether the trigger corresponds to one of 02:20, 12:30, 22:20.